# Jquery can't change the classname after one time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is my code for Dropdown Menu Appear and Disappear..

If the class name is "dropdown pull-right" then the menu will be closed

If the class name is "dropdown pull-right open" then the menu will be opened

```
<li class="dropdown pull-right" id="tobechanged">            
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Admin <b class="caret"></b>              
    </a>
</li>
```

So, i wrote this query

```
$(".dropdown-toggle" ).click(function() {
console.log(document.getElementById("tobechanged").className);
if (document.getElementById("tobechanged").className == "dropdown pull-right" ) {
      console.log('opening menu');
      document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-toggle").className = "dropdown pull-right open";
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('closing menu');
    document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-toggle").className = "dropdown pull-right";
    }

});
```

It works only in the first time. If i change to another page only the console `console.log('opening menu');` works and the class name is changing..

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i make the class name change ?

**Note :** I am using angularjs, so the page won't be reloaded entirely

Comment: Well what is the classname when it does not work?

Comment: @epascarello "dropdown pull-right" .. it consoles as 'opening menu', but the class name is not changing to `dropdown pull-right open`

Comment: Why don't you just use `$("#dropdown-toggle").hasClass("open")`

Comment: @epascarello , i tried to use `toggle` but my class name contains spaces, so  i can't use it.. Can I ?

Comment: @epascarello I can use it.. but is there anything wrong in my code ?

Comment: Toggle should work since all you need to do is toggle open. You are not going to toggle the other two classes. And now I see the bug...You can not set a HTML collection

Comment: @epascarello can you pls tel how can i handle that in toggle ?

Comment: Actually the issue and code above has nothing to do with angularjs. Please remove this tag.

Comment: I do not know what you want to do since you are setting open to some other element. Not sure how "open" will be applied to that element to toggle... Issue is `getElementsByClassName` returns an HTML collection, not a single element.

Comment: @epascarello i tried to console the `getElementsByClassName` and it returns only the class name..

Comment: I am not sure what browser you are using. It returns an array-like collection of elements ....getElement ***s*** By...

Comment: @epascarello But, how it works on first and second time.. it is not working on navigating to third page only... :(

Comment: I am using chrome browser only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix plus some additional improvements; no need to search for the elements a couple of times

```
$(".dropdown-toggle" ).click(function() {
  var el = document.getElementById("tobechanged");
  if (el.className == "dropdown pull-right" ) {
      console.log('opening menu');
      el.className = "dropdown pull-right open";
  }
  else {
      console.log('closing menu');
      el.className = "dropdown pull-right";
  }
});
```

To do it in in JQuery :

```
$(".dropdown-toggle" ).click(function() {
  $(this).closest('#tobechanged').toggleClass('open');
});
```

**Update:**
Demo https://jsfiddle.net/n13svnLL/

Comment: it should work, please check the update for the demo

Comment: Ah, the issue is it works good in first time. and it is not working after 3rd time...

Comment: That's not the behavior I'm experiencing. It works for me every time as demoed in https://jsfiddle.net/n13svnLL/

Comment: If it doesn't work after the first time, it might be caused by another issue in your code

Answer (score 1):

The issue I see is that once you execute the line:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-toggle").className = "dropdown pull-right open";
```

This basically will change your html from :

```
<li class="dropdown pull-right" id="tobechanged">            
   <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="**dropdown-toggle**" aria-expanded="false">
   <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Admin <b class="caret"></b>              
   </a>
</li>
```

into

```
<li class="dropdown pull-right" id="tobechanged">            
   <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="**dropdown pull-right open**" aria-expanded="false">
   <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Admin <b class="caret"></b>              
   </a>
</li>
```

Making basically your element no longer available for click event, because the click is subscribed to an element by class name which you change.

```
$(".dropdown-toggle" )
```

Hope this is not too confusing.

Comment: I would suggest to do this functionality in angularjs. What is the reason of using particularly li elements instead of a <select> with <option> which is a proper dropdown?

Comment: It was a template ! and can you tell me how to do in angularjs ?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you want to achieve so that I can show you a proper example using angular.

Comment: Here is an example of how you can do menu with submenu or just use <select> using angularjs:http://plnkr.co/edit/vzB8sJzXrxWVFK1TaJ10?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the Class of the Parent li Element not the a Element inside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <pre>you are assigning class name only for dropdown-toggle so it will work only one time for that you have to assign same class name to id (tobechanged) as well</pre>

if (document.getElementById("tobechanged").className == "dropdown pull-right" ) {
      console.log('opening menu');
      document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-toggle").className = "dropdown pull-right open";
      document.getElementById("tobechanged").className == "dropdown pull-right open";
}
else
{
       console.log('closing menu');
       document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-toggle").className = "dropdown pull-right";
       document.getElementById("tobechanged").className == "dropdown pull-right"
}
```